# What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?

Tags: velocity, air

I got asked this question for my physics course at college, i'm not the best at airspeed velocities...

> What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?

I still can't find anything to help me, i'm quite stuck and have been googling and asking about on a few forums.

Best help I found was [this](http://style.org/unladenswallow/) page on the subject.

Thank you.

Comment: ....was [the question serious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2R3FvS4xr4)?

Comment: I thought so, I haven't watch that movie so I wouldn't know. Would African or European types of swallows make a difference overall? or could they still achieve the same velocity?

Comment: Well that scene is the only portion in which the question is relevant in the movie. I am not an [ornithologist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithology), so have no idea about the difference between the birds.

Comment: This page http://style.org/unladenswallow/ states their is a difference and is quite helpful. I thought someone might be able to go into more detail so I don't go back to class being all smug when it was a legitimate question.

Comment: This question appears to be a joke rather than a physics question, making it off-topic. Sorry!

Comment: Just say it's $1ussu$ (that's unladen swallow speed unit)

Comment: You know, it's the little things in life...

Comment: I don't really understand just because there is a joke reference that I was unaware of that's makes it less as important as others?

Comment: You could turn this into a good question if you wanted to, asking about aerodynamic properties of birds and such, but since the audience here are physicists and not ornithologists, you're more likely to get a positive response if you do some of the legwork and provide at least some details about swallow shape and other properties, and a bit of looking around for serious research on the topic. Given the popularity of the quote, it wouldn't entirely surprise me if someone has actually investigated this in a "serious" scientific framework.

Comment: Adding to what @Kyle said, the airspeed would be variable too because a bird can choose how fast to fly. So without a specifier like "the top airspeed", it is a useless question.

Comment: You can also try http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=airspeed+velocity+unladen+swallow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the RSB](http://www.rspb.org.uk/wildlife/birdguide/name/s/swallow/migration.aspx):

> Migrating (European) swallows cover 200 miles a day, mainly during daylight, at speeds of 17-22 miles per hour. The maximum flight speed is 35 mph

I think that calculating the flight speed of a bird from first principles would be impossibly difficult as there are just too many variables. The web site you link does get an answer that agrees with the RSPB, but one has to wonder if they knew the answer in advance, and in any case they do a lot of the work by comparing with other birds rather than by *ab initio* calculation.